# Ubuntu Studio Installation Failed - External Command Failed To Finish

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-studio

I created a bootable USB stick with Rufus containing Ubuntu Studio 21.04, at about 75% completion installation stopped with error message: "Installation Failed, External command failed to finish" (Click "Error Message" for details). Appreciate any helpful advice.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNesi.jpg)

USB Stick: Kingston DTEG2 64GB
HDD: WD40EFRX 4TB
MB: ASUS Gamer (UEFI BIOS)
RAM: 16GB

Answer (score 1):

You have Secure Boot enabled, UbuntuStudio installer doesn't seem to support this properly. This answer might help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1347703/1341109