# Issues installing Ubuntu Studio 20.04 at Acer Nitro 5

Tags: live-usb, acer, ubuntu-studio

I have the message error (Trying to translate from portuguese to english)

the external command failed:

the command apt install -y -no-upgrade -o Acquire::gpgc::Options=..ignore-time-conflict shim signed failed while finishing in 300 seconds.
There is any output

Answer (score 1):

You have Secure Boot enabled, and UbuntuStudio installer doesn't support that properly. The package being installed is trying to ask you questions via the terminal - which you can't see. So it hangs.

Option 1: Turn off Secure Boot, it's nearly useless anyway. See the [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_US/) FAQ to help you decide.

Option 2: Install Kubuntu (or some other Ubuntu distro) that supports Secure Boot properly, and then install the [ubuntustudio-installer](https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/) package. In the Kubuntu installer, below the checkbox for proprietary drivers is a checkbox for Secure Boot. You'll need to make up a MOK password and enter it here twice. On your next boot, you will get an incredibly cryptic prompt. Select 'enroll MOK' muddle through the selections and enter the password you provided the installer. After that everything just works.

There is a command line utility for working with MOKs: update-secureboot-policy. You shouldn't need it.

BTW, to watch Netflix, Amazon Primer video, etc, in Firefox, enable DRM in the preferences AND turn off 'Enhanced Tracking Protection' for those sites.

I took option 2 on my Acer Swift 3 Ryzen 7 4700U as a learning experience. I am not using dual boot. Everything seems to be working fine.